# I am trying to convert numbers into their opposite value regardless of whether number is positive or negative

Tags: javascript

I tried this code, it works

```
const opposite = number => -number
```

Code won't run, just trying to experiment with different ideas

```
function opposite(number){
   return Math.abs(number) 
}

opposite(1)
```

What Am I missing here ?

Comment: Multiply by minus one?

Comment: `Math.abs` will always return absolute value..

Comment: `Math.abs` gets the absolute value, not the opposite (it converts negative numbers to positive numbers)

Comment: `I tried this code, it works` so what exactly do you need?

Comment: Just trying to apply different solutions to a same problem so I can get a better understanding working with Javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is running, your just noticing the output for two reasons:

1. `return`ing a value from your function doesn't mean it will be logged to the console. You need to `console.log()` the function call to see its output (the returned value)
2. `Math.abs()` will get the absolute value of a number passed into it (which isn't the same as the opposite). You can think of this as the distance a given number is away from 0. Thus doing `Math.abs(1)` will give `1` not `-1`, perhaps making you think your function isn't working. With this in mind `Math.abs()` will only give you the opposite for numbers which are negative, not positive.

See running example below:

```js
function opposite(number){
   return Math.abs(number) 
}

console.log(opposite(-1)); // returns 1
console.log(opposite(1)); // returns 1
```